# SQL equivalent for type (as in type-script / flow type)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) parameter with defined type in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) fashion.

Something akin to

```
create procedure something
   @myparam 'student' | 'teacher'
as
  ...
```

where `@myparam` can be of either type `'student'` or `'teacher'`.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a procedure where the parameter data type is sql_variant. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Once you receive the parameter, you can check the underlying data type by using the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY function. As an example

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v1, 'BaseType');
```

will return the underlying data type.